# Writing to file doesn't flush content automatically and cause out of memory in Python

Tags: python, file, buffer, flush

I made simple python program to generate big text file:

```
import sys
import random

f = open('data.txt', 'w')
for i in range(100000000):
        f.write(str(i) + "\t" + str(random.randint(0,1000)) + "\n")
f.close()
```

When I launch it using CPython it eat all available OS memory and write nothing to the file.

When I launch it on Jython I get `OutOfMemoryException`.

As far as I understand it stores everything in memory buffer and never did flush before `close()` call.

My question is: how to limit the file buffer and trigger autoflush?
I don't want to call`flush()` manually, I think it's wrong from performance point of view. I want `flush()` to be called automatically when file buffer is overloaded or so.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that `str(i) + "\t" + str(random.randint(0,1000)) + "\n"` would usually be written `%d\t%d\n" % (i, random.randint(0,1000))`. This is a more common style, is more robust, and can have better performance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Buffering is not the problem. The problem is calling the `range()` function with a giant argument, which will attempt to allocate an array with lots of elements. You will get the same error if you just say

```
r = range(100000000)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, and could you give advise to python newbie, what's the python style to implement this properly?

Comment: try using `for i in xrange(10000000)`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [passing in a buffer size](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) to the `open` function?

```
f = open('data.txt', 'w', 5000)
```